# Pandas MultiIndex, rearrange label in a specific level

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling on a simple task, I would like to have a dataframe with two levels of index always ordered in the same way (the values of the levels not the levels themselves). I'm trying something like below but it revert a full dataframe of NaN. On Internet, it's all about the .reorder_levels function, which order the levels and not their values.

The thing is that the list of values for both levels are known but I'm iterating over several DataFrame to display the values in a report and the values of the levels can vary from a DF to another or from one day to another.

What I'm trying looks like this :

```py
Position = Position.loc[[
    x for x in list_commo if x in Position.index.get_level_values(0).to_list()]]
for commo in Position.index.get_level_values(0).to_list():
    Position.loc[commo] = Position.loc[commo].loc[[
        x for x in list_cat if x in Position.loc[commo].index.to_list()]]
```

An example of the DF :

[image: DF]

The first stage, reorder the first level, is easy, when it becomes tricky is to reorder the second level for each occurrence of the first level (not all occurrences of the first level will have the same occurrences of the second level)

Does someone have a good solution for such task?

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: why don't you provide a small reproducible example (as text) and the matching expected output?

Comment: kindly provide reproducible data, with expected output dataframe